# Integration of a function involving ln: $\int \frac{x}{x^2 + 2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Given the function,

$\dfrac{x}{x^2 + 2} $

The integral of the above term produces,

$\frac{1}{2}\ln|x^2 +2| + k$

I do not know how to reach this as I would have given the following term as an integral term,

$2x \ln|x^2 +2|$

Comment: $ x \, dx= \frac12d( x^2)$ So, should the $2$ be in the numerator or in the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help you to use $u$-substitution.  We have:
$$\int \frac x{x^2 + 2} \,dx$$

If we let $u= x^2 + 2 $, then $du = 2x\,dx\;$ or $\;x dx = \frac 12 du$

That gives us $$\frac 12 \int \frac 1u\,du = \frac 12 \ln|u| + c = \frac 12 \ln|x^2 +2| + c$$

Notice that, although $\int \dfrac 1x \,dx = \ln |x| + c$, when we have a *function* of $x$, say $f(x)$ in the denominator, then we need to have $$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx$$ in order to integrate and obtain $\ln|f(x)| + c$

Comment: Thank you for helping out I am however confused about what happens to the numerator,

Comment: You need to understand that $$\int \frac 1{f(x)}\,dx \neq \ln|f(x)| + c$$ if $f(x)$ is a function of x other than the variable x.  We need $$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,dx$$ In this case $f(x) = x^2 + 2$. $f'(x) = 2x$. Since our given numerator is $x$, we can make it $2x$ my multiplying the numerator x by $\frac 12 (2x)$, bringing the $\frac 12$ to the front of the integral, so we have $$\frac 12 \int \frac{f'x}{f(x)}\,dx = \frac 12 \ln|f(x)| +c$$

Comment: Again why is it imperative to multiply by 1/2 thank you very much!

Comment: So that we obtain $2x$ in the numerator:  We start with $x$ in the denominator. Now, $x = \frac 12(2x) =\frac 12 f'(x)$ in the numerator.

Comment: Basically we ignore the original x, we insert the dx term of denominator as new numerator and divide and integer attached to the new numerator by itself am I getting this right, thank you for the effort

Comment: You tell me: Is $x = \frac 12(2x)$?  What is the derivative of the denominator? Answer $2x$. Which we have as long as we keep pull the  factor of $\frac 12$ to the front of the integral.  We did not forget the $x$ in the numerator. That gives us that $$\int \frac x{x^2 + 2}\,dx = \frac 12\int \frac {2x}{x^2+2} \,dx =\frac 12 \int \frac{(x^2 + 2)'}{x^2 + 2 }\,dx$$ $$= \frac 12 \ln|x^2+2| + c$$

Comment: Thanks a lot u do have a lot of patience

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\int \frac{x}{x^2+2}\:dx=\frac12\int \frac{2x}{x^2+2}\:dx=\frac12\int \frac{(x^2+2)'}{(x^2+2)}\:dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

So you look for
$$
\int \frac{x}{x^2 + 2} dx
$$
Do the change of variable : $t = x^2 + 2, \ dt = 2x\; dx$ then :
$$
\int \frac{x}{x^2 + 2} dx = \int \frac{dt / 2}{t} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(t) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for any differentiable $f\neq 0$ and some constant $a\neq 0$:

$$\int \dfrac{f'(x)}{af(x)} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{a} \ln \mid f(x) \mid + C$$

where $C$ is the constant of integration.